# gdalinfo on NetCDF - cell centers or edges?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, netcdf, gdalinfo

I was given a NetCDF file and the gdalinfo result for it shows this:

```
NC_GLOBAL#XORIG=-126.0800018310547
NC_GLOBAL#YORIG=41.45000076293945
```

The gdalinfo command is showing the lower-left cell in the grid, but can anyone tell me if this x,y point is the cell center or the lower-left corner of that cell (i.e.: 1/2 cell width southwest of the cell center)?

Comment: Thank you for taking the [Tour]. Unfortunately, it does stress that only one question can be asked per Question. Please reformat this to be a single question.

Comment: I think it was really one two-part question, but rules are rules. Now edited - please approve it.

Comment: it's very likely to be the centre point, gdal reports the edges. but, netcdf is a wild arena of endless adventure so you can only handwave about these generalities, to really be sure you need more details from the file